# Error checking within loops and executing queries?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, pdo

I need to be able to check whether all elements of an array are valid before doing the queries, if I do it like this:

```
$arr = array(5, 3, 'test', 23, 9);
$query = $members->prepare("insert into mytable(a) values(:a)");

foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if (is_int($val)) {
       $query->execute(array(':a'=>$val));
    }
}
```

I only want to insert the values in the array into the database if all of them are `ints`, but it inserts the first two values before it gets to 'test' in the array. This is just a random example I made up for the problem that I'm having.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: do the int check BEFORE you run the queries. or at least wrap the whole thing in a transaction so you can rollback if any one query fails.

Comment: Transactions would be one way: start transaction before the loop, then rollback on failure of any entry; or commit on success; or validate in one loop, and update in a second loop if all pass validation

Comment: What is the "non random" example of the problem you have? where do you get your arrays?

Comment: Loop through the array and check the elements. Then loop through the array and execute the queries .....

Comment: @YourCommonSense: The OP was correct to create this abstract testcase. Wish we could see it done more often (i.e. _always_)

Comment: -1 because, although this is a well-formed question, it's kinda dumb, no offence. It's trivial to approach this problem by applying divide-and-conquer and some original thought... It's also too localised for SO, more to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways to handel this:

1) loop through all the values and validate it first ( you really should allays validate data that isnt controlled).

2) If your using PDO/INNOdb start a transaction run that loop and on the fail of the validation rollback and break out of the loop.

eg.

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$arr = array(5, 3, 'test', 23, 9);
$query = $members->prepare("insert into mytable(a) values(:a)");
$success = true;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if (is_int($val)) {
       $query->execute(array(':a'=>$val));
    } else {
      $success = false;
      $db->rollback();
      break;

    }
}

if($success) {
 $db->commit();
}
```

Comment: makes sense but shouldnt `$success = false` be above `break;` ?

Comment: yep it should be... will fix it

Answer (score 0):

> I only want to insert the values in the array into the database if all of them are ints

when you need to check an array, a loop is always your friend

```
$fault = 0;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if (!is_int($val)) {
        $fault = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: dont make sense where would i execute the query

Comment: That would go before your code block and then you would wrap your code block in if(!$fault) { /*your code */}

Comment: yeh then i just end up with the same problem i started with

Answer (score 0):

How about http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Example:

```
$arr = array(5, 3, 'test', 23, 9);
$nicearr = array_filter($arr, "getNumbersOnly")

function getNumbersOnly($var)
{
    return is_int($var);
}
```

Then just use $nicearr for your queries/loop, as you can be certain they're all integers.

Comment: This isn't what he asked for, his request was to only do the queries if all the data was valid, this will still run queries while ignoring bad data.

Comment: It's a neat way of getting the valid data. All you'd need is to compare the length of $arr and $nicearr then. if (count($arr) == count($nicearr)) { // Crack on with the db process }